# Android: constructor ContactsAdapter in class ContactsAdapter cannot be applied to given types

Tags: android, arraylist, custom-adapter

i'm trying to populate a ListView with a ArrayList

this is my code:

```
ArrayList<Contact> results = mapper.readValue(response.toString(),
                                new TypeReference<ArrayList<Contact>>() { } );//results are coming OK

                        ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_items, results);//error is here
```

and this is my custom adapter class, with its respective constructor:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Contact> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        contactList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_items, null);
        TextView contactTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactTextView);
        TextView phoneTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phoneTextView);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.smallImageView);
        contactTextView.setText(contactList.get(position).getName());
        phoneTextView.setText(contactList.get(position).getPhone().toString());
        //imageView.setImageResource(animalList.get(position).getAnimalImage());
        return v;
    }

}
```

error:

> Error:(58, 51) error: constructor ContactsAdapter in class
>   ContactsAdapter cannot be applied to given types; required:
>   Context,int,ArrayList found: >,int,ArrayList reason: actual argument
>   > cannot be converted to Context by
>   method invocation conversion

My data is grabbed from a jSON, and it is declared as ArrayList. I've tried some things like modifying the constructor, but i don't get it to work and i'm stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `Adapter` constructor call is apparently inside an anonymous class, so `this` refers to that anonymous class, not the `Context` you need as the first argument. If that code is in an `Activity`, just prepend the `Activity` name; e.g., `MyActivity.this`.

Comment: dude, you make my day!!! your comment should be the best answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error:(58, 51) error: constructor ContactsAdapter in class ContactsAdapter cannot be applied to given types; required: Context,int,ArrayList<Contact> found: <anonymous Listener<JSONArray>>,int,ArrayList<Contact> reason: actual argument <anonymous Listener<JSONArray>> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion

Your `Adapter` constructor call is apparently inside an anonymous class, so `this` refers to that anonymous class, not the `Context` you need as the first argument. If that code is in an `Activity`, just prepend the `Activity` name to `this`; e.g., `MyActivity.this`.

```
ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(MyActivity.this,
                                              R.layout.list_view_items,
                                              results);
```

Comment: i could stay 2 more days trying and failing without your answer. thank you!